# SELECT and JOIN column not in Group by function

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have to join two different table to get my result. 
The table 'Resource' it is simple, while the table 'Dimension.[Code]' contains, among the others, a column with different values (i.e :

`Code
 SILO
 GRADE 
 OTHER 1
 OTHER2`

This is the reason why a join twice that column to get two different columns called GRADE and SILO.

Now, I have a query that selects the maximum value of a grade within the group as follows:

```
`SELECT 
R.[ID] -- If I inserted that here, it is not working obviously.
       -- This cannot But this is the additional column I need (see later)
 DD_SILO.[Value] DIR , 
 max(R.[GRADE]) GRADE_DIR
 FROM [Resource] R
LEFT JOIN 
Dimension DD_SILO ON  R.[ID] = DD_SILO.[ID] AND DD_SILO.[Code] = 'SILO'
   group by DD_SILO.[Value]'
```

What I need is basically to have, beside GRADE AND SILO, also the ID name, which is contained into the [Resource] table.
Please notice that [Resource].ID = [Dimension].ID

I would have solved the problem with ROW_NUMBER () to select the highest within the group, avoiding then then 'group by', but as the query has to be inserted in a bigger one, that would take too much time to run. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

Comment: why do You left join on the same table twice with different condition. Once ID = ID, the other time GRADE = VALUE ?

Comment: You are right. Now the query is updated. The reason is that the same column can be found in both tables, so before I was using Dimension instead of Resource for the GRADE column. Please now refer to the above updated query.

Comment: check my answer and comment there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use a virtual table something like: -

```
`
select
     a.max_grade_silo,
     a.max_grade_value,
     (select max(r.id) 
        from [resource] r,
             [dimension] d
        where r.[ID] = d.[ID] and
              d.[CODE]= 'SILO' and
              r.[GRADE] = a.[max_grade_value] 
     ),
     max_grade_silo a
from
(SELECT 
     DD_SILO.[Value] DIR , 
     max(R.[GRADE]) GRADE_DIR
     FROM [Resource] R
    LEFT JOIN 
    Dimension DD_SILO ON  R.[ID] = DD_SILO.[ID] AND DD_SILO.[Code] = 'SILO'
       group by DD_SILO.[Value]
) temp_result (max_grade_silo, max_grade_value)
'
```

Probably better to look at normalizing the tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
MAX(R.[ID]) as ID ,
 DD_SILO.[Value] DIR , 
 max(R.[GRADE]) GRADE_DIR
 FROM [Resource] R
LEFT JOIN 
Dimension DD_SILO ON  R.[ID] = DD_SILO.[ID] AND DD_SILO.[Code] = 'SILO'
   group by DD_SILO.[Value]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Nevertheless, due to the structure of the table, the query you suggest does not return the desired result. Is there any way to select (with sub query) the R.[ID] as it is in order to avoid to insert the variable in any aggregate function?

Comment: The query you propose actually return the actual max(ID) which is not linked with the GRADE and SILO. I would like to have the ID which is the correspondent of the Grade and Silo value, not just the max one